fstab settings disappeared after rebooting on ubuntu 20.04
An Ubuntu VM is configured in an Azure environment.
I had previously entered settings in fstab, but they were lost after rebooting. Do you know what could cause the fstab settings to disappear after a reboot?
However, this issue occurred only once. I set fstab again and rebooted, and the entries remained intact.
If you have any insights on this matter, please let me know. I would appreciate it.

is it possible that the fstab file was not saved the first time round or that it was not placed in the correct directory (~/etc/)
